# NiFi: start new session from groovy script during script runtime

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have in NiFi 1.11 an ExecuteScript with Groovy. The script uses big xml data and generates thousends of new NiFi sessions

All these new session are generated with:

```
newFlowFile = session.create()
newFlowFile = session.write(newFlowFile, 
    {inStream, outStream ->
        outStream.write(recordOut.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    } as StreamCallback )
session.transfer(newFlowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

This works well.
But the new sessions are only started after the script is ended.

Example:
The script takes 60 minutes to handle the xml data and generates 50.000 new sessions. So after the 60 minutes all new sessions are put to the queue.

Question:
Is it possible to change the groovy code, so that the new sessions are starting in the moment that the code above is called and not waiting for the script to end?

Thanx
Frank

Comment: Why the need for creating additional sessions?

Comment: "Why the need for creating additional sessions?" -> 
the input ist a huge xml file. for each object of type 'x' in the xml-structure I have to create a new flowfile to handle the information of this object

Comment: You can transfer as many FlowFiles as you want in a single session, you'd only want to create new sessions if you don't want to roll back the whole thing if one FlowFile fails. Often times though you want to do all your processing in one session and if anything goes wrong, you roll it back. I think the only time I've seen multiple sessions used in a case like this is when you need the FlowFiles to get to the next processor before you're finished processing everything. But even in that case you can just commit() the session and keep using the same one.